# Calling an array using object syntax in PHP

Tags: php, yii

I'm getting the error "Trying to get property of non-object" when attempting to call an array using php object syntax.

```
Yii::log(print_r($terminalReport->terminal->started_at,true));
```

That line will actually log the started_at time correctly and then error out.

This code works on a production server. However, this is not working on a recently set up dev environment.

Is there a PHP module I'm missing that will allow me to call an array using that syntax without throwing an error?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
2015/08/25 13:22:12 [error] [php] Trying to get property of non-object (/PATH/app/protected/models/TerminalReportManager.php:33)
Stack trace:
#0 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(3100): TerminalController->renderInternal()
#1 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(3524): TerminalController->renderFile()
#2 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(3492): TerminalController->renderPartial()
#3 /PATH/app/protected/controllers/TerminalController.php(38): TerminalController->render()
#4 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(3760): TerminalController->actionIndex()
#5 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(3272): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#6 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(6526): TerminalController->runAction()
#7 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(6535): CFilterChain->run()
#8 /PATH/app/protected/components/system/Controller.php(60): AccessControlFilter->filter()
#9 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(6568): TerminalController->filterAccessControl()
#10 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(6523): CInlineFilter->filter()
#11 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(3262): CFilterChain->run()
#12 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(3247): TerminalController->runActionWithFilters()
#13 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(1689): TerminalController->run()
#14 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(1609): CWebApplication->runController()
#15 /PATH/framework/yiilite.php(1135): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#16 /PATH/app/index.php(21): CWebApplication->run()
REQUEST_URI=/terminal
```

Comment: unlikely to be a php issue, more like missing data (either `terminal` is null, or `started_at` is null).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how either of those could be null. When I run that log statement the correct time for started_at is logged. But an error is still thrown for that line

Comment: hmmm ... maybe something is incorrectly set-up in your dev environment, and the `Yii::log` method barfs **after** logging correctly.

Comment: It must be something in the dev environment. Its not just the Yii log that errors out. I just put that in for testing but was surprised to see it actually outputting the correct time

Comment: What is the line after this? If started_at is logged correctly, then this is not what is causing your issue. Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Added the full stack trace in an edit

Comment: And can you also give the method that contains line 33 of TerminalReportManager?

Comment: For that instance I was logging the var_dump:
Yii::log(print_r(var_dump($terminalReport->terminal),true));

Comment: Sidenote: var_dump will echo, not return a value, so your print_r() won't contain data. Can you provide all relevant code that's in that class and mark line 33?

Comment: I think this may actually be related to the error_reporting level. When running 'php -i | grep error_reporting' on this instance I get 'error_reporting => 22527 => 22527'

On a working dev instance I get:  error_reporting => no value => no value

Comment: The error_reporting level is irrelevant for this issue. If it would be 0 (no error reporting), you wouldn't get any error message. You can change error_reporting in your dev php.ini to the same value as your production php.ini. Still, I can't help without the code of TerminalReportManager (and perhaps the view code that is calling it).

Answer (score 0):

Either `$terminalReport` or its relation `terminal` does not exist in the database on your dev environment. Debug this code with a `var_dump` of `$terminalReport` and `$terminalReport->terminal` to check which value is null.

Comment: Is it possible that the relation does not exist even though the correct time for started_at is being logged?

Comment: Yes, probably the related record for `terminal` does not exist in your dev database, so you should create it or import a mysql dump from production on your dev to work with the same data.

Comment: Interestingly I am working off of a production DB dump

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($terminalReport)` and `var_dump($terminalReport->terminal)` to verify that both values are definitely not null? Did you also verify that all required data is in the dev database?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the errors I was receiving were actually valid errors but they should have been ignored for this application.

By setting error_reporting in my php.ini to

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR
```

I was able to solve this issue.

Comment: So the data didn't exist in the database or what is causing the error? I assume that you want the error to be fixed?

Comment: It looks like when the data doesn't exist this is treating it as null. The error that was being thrown interrupted that process. Obviously, this probably isn't the best solution and it is something that will be addressed. At this point however, my dev instance is up and running and I can resume getting some work done.

Comment: Indeed, when your relation does not match a record it will return null, that's why I asked you to debug those variables separately. You can check for null values to prevent this issue when data would go missing in the future.